# Why does the program not call the method "onLocationChanged"?

Tags: android-studio, android-gps

i wrote this simple code for getting the GPS coordinates but it doesnt call the method "onChangedLocation". I know it should jump into the method only when the coordinates change, but at first start it always should jump into that method or not?

It should display the longtitude and latitude in the catlog.

Im using my phone for debugging.

```
package tabs;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


import androfenix.whetoo.R;


public class Tab1 extends ListFragment implements LocationListener {

    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_local, container, false);

        String[] abc = {"Message1", "Message2", "Message3", "Message1", "Message2", "Message3", "Message1", "Message2", "Message3", "Message1", "Message2", "Message3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, abc);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "onLocationChanged wird aufgerufen");
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        String name = String.valueOf(longitude);
        Log.d("longtitude", name);

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        String name2 = String.valueOf(latitude);
        Log.d("latitude", name2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
}
```

Comment: check gps is enabled  and refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

Comment: GPS is enabled and thanks for your link. I already was studying your link before, but they implement the google play service. But i want only a simple code for getting the coordinates using my phones "GPS Service"